# pass list<string> as parameter to webservice

Tags: salesforce, apex-code

Please help!!

**What is the correct way to send List of String as a parameter to webservice ?**

List < SObject > ObjectContents; // {get; set;}  contains records of selected object 
List str3 = new List ();
String FormattedValue;

```
 for (SObject a :  for (SObject a : ObjectContents)) // for (SObject a : ObjectContents)
 {
 for(String field:fieldApis){  //  fieldApis contains list of fieldnames
            FormattedValue = '\'' + a.get(field) + '\'' ;  //fetches value of each field
  }

  str3.add(FormattedValue );
   }

    //sending data to webservice
sqlArray19.ArrayOfstring a= new sqlArray19.ArrayOfstring();  
SQLServerConnector9.BasicHttpBinding_IService1 stub = new SQLServerConnector9.BasicHttpBinding_IService1();
```

//sqlArray19 and SQLServerConnector9 classes were formed while importing wsdl into Salesforce

```
List<String> insertMsg = stub.InsertQuery(str3); // getting error in this line 

"Compile Error: Method does not exist or incorrect signature: [SQLServerConnector9.BasicHttpBinding_IService1].InsertQuery(LIST<String>)"
```

**.net webservice which will fetch values from Salesforce and return those values**

```
 public List<String> InsertQuery(List<String> Values)
    {
        return Values ;
    }
```

Comment: By the way you can ask your question about salesforce directly at http://salesforce.stackexchange.com/

Answer (score 0):

Collections can be troublesome data types when working across platforms with web services. Try converting your List into a string[] (and changing your method, of course).